# LaTeX3 - Parsing an argument to apply specific macros

Tags: latex3, parsing

In the following code, I would like to parse the argument of `\parseanduse` such as to "achieve" the examples shown.

Each time a `o` is met, the following integer should be used to call the macro `\macroO`. **There is no upper bound for the integers.**

There is a similar feature with `r` and `a` and the macros `\macroR` and `\macroA`.

What would be the best way to do that in LaTeX3?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\macroO}{m}{Option [#1] ,}
\NewDocumentCommand{\macroR}{m}{Option $<$#1$>$ ,}
\NewDocumentCommand{\macroA}{m}{Argument #1 ,}

\NewDocumentCommand{\parseanduse}{m}{???}


\begin{document}

\parseanduse{o1r2a3}

same as

\macroO{1}\macroR{2}\macroA{3}


\bigskip


\parseanduse{o1r2a3o11r222a3333}

same as

\macroO{1}\macroR{2}\macroA{3}\macroO{11}\macroR{222}\macroA{3333}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the argument guaranteed to contain no spaces and no braces?

Comment: Yes, it should be without any spaces.

Comment: No. That is why I have put examples with `11`, `222`, and `3333`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can parse via regular expressions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\parseanduse}{m}
 {
  \projetmbc_parseanduse:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\macroO}{m}
 {
  \projetmbc_macro_o:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\macroR}{m}
 {
  \projetmbc_macro_r:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\macroA}{m}
 {
  \projetmbc_macro_a:n { #1 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__projetmbc_parseanduse_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \projetmbc_parseanduse:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__projetmbc_parseanduse_tl { #1 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN
   { (o|r|a)([[:digit:]]*) } % search o or r or a followed by digits
   { \c{projetmbc_macro_\1:n} \cB\{\2\cE\} } % replace with macro and braces
   \l__projetmbc_parseanduse_tl
  \tl_use:N \l__projetmbc_parseanduse_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \projetmbc_macro_o:n
 {
  Option~[#1]~,
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \projetmbc_macro_r:n
 {
  Option~$<$#1$>$~,
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \projetmbc_macro_a:n
 {
  Argument~#1~,
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\parseanduse{o1r2a3}

same as

\macroO{1}\macroR{2}\macroA{3}

\bigskip

\parseanduse{o1r2a3o11r222a3333}

same as

\macroO{1}\macroR{2}\macroA{3}\macroO{11}\macroR{222}\macroA{3333}

\bigskip

\parseanduse{a1o2r3o11r222a3333}

same as

\macroA{1}\macroO{2}\macroR{3}\macroO{11}\macroR{222}\macroA{3333}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A fully expandable version that is quite readable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% these are just to check the output
\NewDocumentCommand{\macroO}{m}
 {
  \projetmbc_macro_o:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\macroR}{m}
 {
  \projetmbc_macro_r:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\macroA}{m}
 {
  \projetmbc_macro_a:n { #1 }
 }

% the main command
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\parseanduse}{m}
 {
  \projetmbc_parseanduse:n { #1 }
 }


% we assume that the argument starts with a letter
% error checks can be added
% \q_nil is appended to the list
\cs_new:Nn \projetmbc_parseanduse:n
 {
  \__projetmbc_parseanduse_start:N #1 \q_nil
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__projetmbc_parseanduse_start:N
 {% #1 is a letter, start with empty second argument and scan the next token
  \__projetmbc_parseanduse_next:nnN { #1 } { }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__projetmbc_parseanduse_next:nnN
 {
  \quark_if_nil:NTF #3
   {% we reached the end, issue the macro and the collected argument
    \use:c { projetmbc_macro_#1:n } { #2 }
   }
   {% scan the next token
    \int_compare:nTF { `0 <= `#3 <= `9 }
     {% we found a digit, append it to the candidate second argument
      \__projetmbc_parseanduse_next:nnN { #1 } { #2#3 }
     }
     {% we found a letter, issue the macro and the collected argument
      \use:c { projetmbc_macro_#1:n } { #2 }
      % restart the recursion
      \__projetmbc_parseanduse_start:N #3
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \projetmbc_macro_o:n
 {
  Option~[#1]~,
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \projetmbc_macro_r:n
 {
  Option~$<$#1$>$~,
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \projetmbc_macro_a:n
 {
  Argument~#1~,
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\parseanduse{o1r2a3}

same as

\macroO{1}\macroR{2}\macroA{3}

\bigskip

\parseanduse{o1r2a3o11r222a3333}

same as

\macroO{1}\macroR{2}\macroA{3}\macroO{11}\macroR{222}\macroA{3333}

\bigskip

\parseanduse{a1o2r3o11r222a3333}

same as

\macroA{1}\macroO{2}\macroR{3}\macroO{11}\macroR{222}\macroA{3333}

\edef\test{\parseanduse{a1o2r3o11r222a3333}}
\texttt{\meaning\test}

\end{document}
```

In the last lines the macros `\projetmbc_macro_(o|r|a):n` are not expanded because they're protected. But if they are fully expandable, there will be no problem.

[image]

Comment: That's great! Can you remember me the utility of `\cB` and `\cE`?

Comment: @projetmbc They ensure that the following character token will be of category code 1 or 2 respectively.

Comment: Thanks "until" the next question... :-)

Comment: @projetmbc I've slightly improved the code.

Comment: Ok. I have seen. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The following is pretty low-level code, but shows how one could achieve this with a fully expandable loop. The loop can do more than you originally asked for (it does work with spaces and braced parts inside the argument of the individual macros).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\macroO}{m}{Option [#1] ,}
\NewDocumentCommand{\macroR}{m}{Option $<$#1$>$ ,}
\NewDocumentCommand{\macroA}{m}{Argument #1 ,}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnn { projetmbc } { unknown-function }
  { Unknown~ function~ `#1'.~ Giving~ up. }
\scan_new:N \s__projetmbc_stop
\scan_new:N \s__projetmbc_mark
\cs_new:Npn \__projectmbc_gobble_to_stop:w #1 \s__projetmbc_stop {}
\cs_new:Npn \__projectmbc_gobble_to_mark:w #1 \s__projetmbc_mark {}
\cs_new:Npn \__projetmbc_brace_open: { { \if_false: } \fi: }
\cs_new:Npn \__projetmbc_brace_close: { \if_false: { \fi: } }
\cs_new:Npn \projetmbc_parse_loop:n #1
  {
    \use:e
      { \__projetmbc_parse_loop:N #1 {\s__projetmbc_mark}~ \s__projetmbc_stop }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__projetmbc_parse_loop:N #1
  {
    \cs_if_exist:cTF { macro \str_uppercase:n {#1} }
      {
        \exp_not:c { macro \str_uppercase:n {#1} }
        \__projetmbc_brace_open:
        \__projetmbc_parse_loop_collect:w
      }
      {
        \msg_expandable_error:nnn { projetmbc } { unknown-function } {#1}
        \__projectmbc_gobble_to_stop:w
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__projetmbc_parse_loop_collect:w #1 \s__projetmbc_stop
  {
    \tl_if_head_is_group:nTF {#1}
      \__projetmbc_parse_loop_group:nw
      {
        \tl_if_head_is_space:nTF {#1}
          \__projetmbc_parse_loop_space:w
          \__projetmbc_parse_loop_normal:Nw
      }
    #1 \s__projetmbc_stop
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__projetmbc_parse_loop_group:nw #1
  {
    \__projectmbc_gobble_to_mark:w
      #1 \__projetmbc_parse_loop_final:w \s__projetmbc_mark
    { \exp_not:n {#1} }
    \__projetmbc_parse_loop_collect:w
  }
\use:n { \cs_new:Npn \__projetmbc_parse_loop_space:w } ~
  { ~ \__projetmbc_parse_loop_collect:w }
\cs_new:Npn \__projetmbc_parse_loop_normal:Nw #1
  {
    \cs_if_exist:cTF { macro \str_uppercase:n {#1} }
      {
        \__projetmbc_brace_close:
        \exp_not:c { macro \str_uppercase:n {#1} }
        \__projetmbc_brace_open:
      }
      { \exp_not:n {#1} }
    \__projetmbc_parse_loop_collect:w
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__projetmbc_parse_loop_final:w #1 \s__projetmbc_stop
  { \__projetmbc_brace_close: }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \parseanduse { m }
  { \projetmbc_parse_loop:n {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\parseanduse{o1r2a3}

same as

\macroO{1}\macroR{2}\macroA{3}


\bigskip


\parseanduse{o1r2a3o11r222a3333}

same as

\macroO{1}\macroR{2}\macroA{3}\macroO{11}\macroR{222}\macroA{3333}

\parseanduse{o\textcolor{red}{abc}1r2a3}

same as

\macroO{\textcolor{red}{abc}1}\macroR{2}\macroA{3}

\end{document}
```

Also, a reduced version that only works for the original input syntax (only `N`-type arguments):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\macroO}{m}{Option [#1] ,}
\NewDocumentCommand{\macroR}{m}{Option $<$#1$>$ ,}
\NewDocumentCommand{\macroA}{m}{Argument #1 ,}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnn { projetmbc } { unknown-function }
  { Unknown~ function~ `#1'.~ Giving~ up. }
\scan_new:N \s__projetmbc_stop
\scan_new:N \s__projetmbc_mark
\cs_new:Npn \__projectmbc_gobble_to_stop:w #1 \s__projetmbc_stop {}
\cs_new:Npn \__projectmbc_gobble_to_mark:w #1 \s__projetmbc_mark {}
% these two macros will leave one unmatched brace when fully expanded, this
% works because TeX doesn't check for brace balancing when gobbling the
% remainder of an \if-construct.
\cs_new:Npn \__projetmbc_brace_open: { { \if_false: } \fi: }
\cs_new:Npn \__projetmbc_brace_close: { \if_false: { \fi: } }
\cs_new:Npn \projetmbc_parse_loop:n #1
  {
    % the loop works inside an expansion context which is started here, as the
    % end marker we use \s__projetmbc_mark, and as the terminal marker we use
    % \s__projetmbc_stop (to gobble the remainder of the current iteration)
    \use:e
      { \__projetmbc_parse_loop:N #1 \s__projetmbc_mark \s__projetmbc_stop }
  }
% the first iteration differs from consecutive ones. It is enforced that the
% argument starts with one of the macros, else an error is thrown and the
% remainder gobbled
\cs_new:Npn \__projetmbc_parse_loop:N #1
  {
    % check whether macro exists
    \cs_if_exist:cTF { macro \str_uppercase:n {#1} }
      {
        % if so build the name and leave an unmatched opening brace (since we're
        % in an expansion context this does no harm as we will have it closed
        % when we're done)
        \exp_not:c { macro \str_uppercase:n {#1} }
        \__projetmbc_brace_open:
        \__projetmbc_parse_loop_aux:N
      }
      {
        \msg_expandable_error:nnn { projetmbc } { unknown-function } {#1}
        \__projectmbc_gobble_to_stop:w
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__projetmbc_parse_loop_aux:N #1
  {
    % all following iterations must check whether the loop is done. This is done
    % in a very fast manner. Assuming that no valid user input will contain the
    % end marker \s__projetmbc_mark, #1 can only be exactly that token when
    % we're done. So in that case only #1 is gobbled and the final action
    % executed, else everything until the first \s__projetmbc_mark is gobbled.
    \__projectmbc_gobble_to_mark:w
      #1 \__projetmbc_parse_loop_final:w \s__projetmbc_mark
    \cs_if_exist:cTF { macro \str_uppercase:n {#1} }
      {
        % if the current token is one of the macro starting ones we need to
        % close the argument of the preceding macro. Afterwards build the new
        % macro and start its argument.
        \__projetmbc_brace_close:
        \exp_not:c { macro \str_uppercase:n {#1} }
        \__projetmbc_brace_open:
      }
      % everything else should just remain there, we protect it from further
      % expanding.
      { \exp_not:n {#1} }
    % call the next iteration
    \__projetmbc_parse_loop_aux:N
  }
% the final action needs to close the argument of the last macro after removing
% the remainder of the last iteration from the input
\cs_new:Npn \__projetmbc_parse_loop_final:w #1 \s__projetmbc_stop
  { \__projetmbc_brace_close: }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \parseanduse { m }
  { \projetmbc_parse_loop:n {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\parseanduse{o1r2a3}

same as

\macroO{1}\macroR{2}\macroA{3}


\bigskip


\parseanduse{o1r2a3o11r222a3333}

same as

\macroO{1}\macroR{2}\macroA{3}\macroO{11}\macroR{222}\macroA{3333}

\end{document}
```

Result of the second version:

[image]

Comment: If I understand well in your code you loop over the argument and when the good character is found you continue to find the integer after suchas to apply the good macro. Am I right?

Comment: Your code is hard to maintain but I will keep it as an exercise. I would like to write a french tutorial about LaTeX3. Being a noob, this should be an easy-to-follow tutorial. :-)

Comment: So no looping with brace tricks? How unfortunate :) If you want to understand this, you should start with the second, way more simple variant. If I find the time later today I'll add some explanations to the code.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for the clarifications.

Comment: @projetmbc I've included some wordy explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Easy with a token cycle.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\macroO}{m}{Option [#1] ,}
\NewDocumentCommand{\macroR}{m}{Option $<$#1$>$ ,}
\NewDocumentCommand{\macroA}{m}{Argument #1 ,}

\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\parseanduse[1]{\tokcycle{%
    \ifx o##1\def\z{}\parsearg{O}\else
    \ifx r##1\def\z{}\parsearg{R}\else
    \ifx a##1\def\z{}\parsearg{A}\fi\fi\fi
  }{}{}{}{#1}\the\cytoks}

\def\parsearg#1{%
  \tcpopappto\z
  \tcpeek\zz
  \tctestifcatnx 0\zz
    {\parsearg{#1}}%
    {\csname macro#1\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\z}}}

\begin{document}

\parseanduse{o1r2a3}

same as

\macroO{1}\macroR{2}\macroA{3}

\bigskip
\parseanduse{o1r2a3o11r222a3333}

same as

\macroO{1}\macroR{2}\macroA{3}\macroO{11}\macroR{222}\macroA{3333}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And if one adopted the convention of the macro suffix letters having the same letter-case as the shorthand (taken here as lowercase), the token cycle would be even easier:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\macroo}{m}{Option [#1] ,}
\NewDocumentCommand{\macror}{m}{Option $<$#1$>$ ,}
\NewDocumentCommand{\macroa}{m}{Argument #1 ,}

\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\parseanduse[1]{%
  \tokcycle{\def\z{}\parsearg{##1}}{}{}{}{#1}\the\cytoks}

\def\parsearg#1{%
  \tcpopappto\z
  \tcpeek\zz
  \tctestifcatnx 0\zz
    {\parsearg{#1}}%
    {\csname macro#1\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\z}}}

\begin{document}

\parseanduse{o1r2a3}

same as

\macroo{1}\macror{2}\macroa{3}

\bigskip
\parseanduse{o1r2a3o11r222a3333}

same as

\macroo{1}\macror{2}\macroa{3}\macroo{11}\macror{222}\macroa{3333}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Easy but a little boring to maintain.

Answer (score 4):

Just for comparison, what you can do only with TeX primitives:

```
\def\macroO#1{Option [#1], }
\def\macroR#1{Option $<$#1$>$, }
\def\macroA#1{Argument #1, }

\def\parseanduse#1{\parseanduseX#1or}
\def\parseanduseX o{\parseanduseO}
\def\parseanduseO #1r{\ifx^#1^\else\macroO{#1}\expandafter\parseanduseR\fi}
\def\parseanduseR #1a{\macroR{#1}\parseanduseA}
\def\parseanduseA #1o{\macroA{#1}\parseanduseO}

% Test:
\parseanduse{o1r2a3o11r222a3333}
```

OK, the following second example accepts the "commands" o, r, a in arbitrary order and it is fully expandable and uses only TeX primitives. We don't need Expl3.

```
\def\afterfi#1#2\fi{\fi#1}
\def\isdigit #1#2{%
   \ifnum #21\else0\fi=\ifnum`#1>`9 0\else \ifnum`#1<`0 0\else 1\fi\fi\space
}
\def\scandigits#1#2#3{\isdigit#3\iftrue
   \afterfi{\scandigits#1{#2#3}}\else\afterfi{#1{#2}#3}\fi
}
\def\parseanduse#1{\parseanduseX#1E}
\def\parseanduseX#1{\ifx E#1\else
   \afterfi{\expandafter\scandigits\csname macro#1\endcsname{}}\fi
}
\def\macroo#1{\macroO{#1}\parseanduseX}
\def\macror#1{\macroR{#1}\parseanduseX}
\def\macroa#1{\macroA{#1}\parseanduseX}

\def\macroO#1{Option [#1], }
\def\macroR#1{Option $<$#1$>$, }
\def\macroA#1{Argument #1, }

\parseanduse{o1r2a3o11r222a3333a13}
```

Comment: Instructive even if I have decided to only code in LaTeX3 (using easy to maintain codes). Your code imposes the order of the writing of the `o`, `r` and `a`. No?

Comment: @egreg You are right.

Comment: *"We don't need Expl3."* Me I need it. :-)